# regex: match all subscripts in an html file except a specific one

Tags: regex, r

I want to remove all subscripts from a piece of html code, except the subscript “rep”.

For instance, the string `"t<sub>i</sub>(10) = 23, p<sub>rep</sub>=.2"` should become: `"t(10) = 23, p<sub>rep</sub>=.2"`

I was trying things like:

```
txt <- "t<sub>i</sub>(10) = 23, p<sub>rep</sub>=.2"
gsub(pattern="<sub>(?!rep).*</sub>",replacement="",txt,perl=TRUE)
```

But the problem is that this line of code deletes *everything* between the first `<sub>` and the last `</sub>` in the html file...

Comment: Your pattern is greedy. Make it ungreedy by adding a `?` at the end. Like so: `"<sub>(?!rep).*?</sub>`. Better yet, use a real HTML parser to achieve this.

Comment: great! that seems to do the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use a **Parser** when dealing with HTML, but to explain your problem...

The issue is that `.*` will go all the way down the string  then eventually [backtrack](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) to allow the closing tag to match. As soon as it backtracks to the second closing tag the regular expression will match.

The simple fix is to follow `.*` with `?` to prevent **greediness**. What this means is look for any character (*except newline*) and find (`0` or more) until you get to a closing tag. Once you specify the question mark `?`, you're telling the regex engine (**do not be greedy..** as soon as you find a closing tag... **stop...**)

```
txt <- 't<sub>i</sub>(10) = 23, p<sub>rep</sub>=.2'
gsub('<sub>(?!rep).*?</sub>', '', txt, perl=T)
# [1] "t(10) = 23, p<sub>rep</sub>=.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `XML` library to parse the html. You can select the nodes you want to remove and use `removeNodes`:

```
library(XML)
xData <- htmlParse("t<sub>i</sub>(10) = 23, p<sub>rep</sub>=.2")
remNodes <- xData['//sub[not(contains(., "rep"))]']
removeNodes(remNodes)
> xData
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
  <html><body>t(10) = 23, p<sub>rep</sub>=.2</body></html>
```

Comment: thanks! but why is using a parser better than just the non greedy regex?

Comment: At this point someone will normally point you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: oh dear, i have " given in to Them and their blasphemous ways which doom us all to inhuman toil for the One whose Name cannot be expressed in the Basic Multilingual Plane". for now, the regex seems to work fine, but i'll see if i can change my regex into a parser. thanks!